# Upgrading highcharts version from 4.1 to 7.12 getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to upgrade highcharts version keeping getting error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined

**My project uses following libraries Jquery, dojo, backbone, underscore.**

Here is my index.html and order of libraries I am including, I used following link to download highcharts "https://www.highcharts.com/blog/download/" from that downloaded highcharts 7.1.2

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <script>
                var dojoConfig = {
                        parseOnLoad: true,
                        locale: 'en',
                        async: true,
                    packages: [
                        { name: "app", location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, "") + "js/app" },             
                        { name: "bootstrapmap", location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, "") + "libs/bower/bootstrap-map-js/src/js", main: "bootstrapmap" },
                        { name: "backbone", location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, "") + "libs/bower/backbone", main: "backbone" },
                        { name: "underscore", location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, "") + "libs/bower/underscore", main: "underscore" }
                        ]
                    };
            </script>
                <script src="libs/jsapi/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="claro">
            <div class="loading">
                <img src="img/spinner.gif" class="loading-spinner" />
                <img src="img/loading.png" class="loading-img img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <script src="libs/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="libs/bower/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
                <script src="libs/highcharts-regression.js"></script>
                <script src="libs/bower/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
                <script src="libs/bower/highcharts/modules/export-data.js"></script>
            <script src="libs/bootstrap.custom.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to upgrade highcharts version from 4.1 to 7.1.2 and Downloaded whole new highcharts version bundled, added that bundle in project and added the following script tags in body after jquery,  highchart js and modules like highcharts-regression, exporting and accessibility in to my project, I am keeping getting error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined, If I include my old 4.1 version it is working fine, I am keeping getting error if I include new version Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined, while I checked Highcharts is not available on window causing that, I am not sure even though I included required library I am still getting that error.

**Recent Findings:**
If I upgrade to version 4.1 to any version of 5 it is working fine, upgrading to 6 or version 7 not working, getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined**

Comment: Where do you get this error? Could you prepare a package with your simplified project to show this issue and instructions on how to run it?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel , Recent Findings: If I upgrade to version 4.1 to any version of 5 it is working fine, upgrading to 6 or version 7 not working, getting Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined in the console window.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my own issue, Dojo is the cause of Issue. 
Adding the highchart libraries after dojo script tag caused issued,

**solution:** 
Adding highchart(7.1.2) script tag before the dojo script tag, It worked fine

**working Code:**

```
    <script src="libs/highcharts-regression.js"></script> 

    <script src="libs/bower/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script src="libs/bower/highcharts/modules/export-data.js"></script>

    <script src="libs/bower/highcharts/modules/accessibility.js"></script>



    <script src="libs/jsapi/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
```

Comment: I have a question on [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239291/6854117) can you please check it out?